# Flutter navigation removing in between routes

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

In my flutter app I want to **remove in between routes** so when the user press back it will go the previous to previous screen. following is my screen flow.

1. Dashboard landing screen.
2. User clicks on the **List Topic** button and lands on **List of Topics** page.
3. User clicks on **Create New Topic** and lands on new page with form to fill with basic info for the topic.
4. After filling the form user clicks on the **save** button and **lands on the new page** with the topic details he just created.
5. Now if user clicks back, he/she should land on **List of Topics** page instead of **Create New Topic** page.
6. Also if he press back again form the **List of Topics** page, he should see the dashboard instead of exiting the app.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `pushReplacement` instead of `push`, when you whant to skip the page at going `back`.

[image]

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter naviagtion',
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: DashboardLandingScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class DashboardLandingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static Route route() => MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => DashboardLandingScreen(),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Dashboard landing screen.'),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('List of Topics'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                TopicsListScreen.route(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TopicsListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static Route route() => MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => TopicsListScreen(),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('List of Topics'),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Create New Topic'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                NewTopic.route(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewTopic extends StatelessWidget {
  static Route route() => MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => NewTopic(),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('page: new topic'),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Save'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                CreatedTopicDetails.route(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CreatedTopicDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  static Route route() => MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => CreatedTopicDetails(),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text('page: created topic details'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help @Kherel

Comment: I'm happy to help. Have a nice day @Sam.